# i want to print the integer always subtacted by 3

Tags: javascript, for-loop, integer

i want to print like this 20 17 14 11 8. it should always subtract with 3

here is my code

```
let cv= 10
let sum=0

for(let i=20;i>5;i--){
    sum=i-3
    console.log(sum)
}
```

Comment: what are the condition to stop printing?

Comment: in you example, `sum` is never set to 10. What you are doing here is setting `i` to 20, and then subtract 1 for each loop, and then subtract 3 from each iteration.

In the first loop, `i` is set to 19, and then subtracts 3 and sets `sum` to 16.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help:

```js
for(let i = 20; i > 5; i = i-3){
    console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reducing i by 1 in each iteration, reduce it by 3.

```js
for(let i = 20; i > 5; i -= 3){
    console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prints if sum >= 0.

```
let sum = 20
const subBy = 3

while(sum >= subBy){
  sum -= subBy
  console.log(sum)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this - here is your answer

input value x = 20 or anything

```js
let x = 20;
let y =  Math.trunc(x/3);

for(let i=1; i<=y; i++){
    a = x - (3*i);
    console.log(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

and you can also start loop from 0

```
let x = 20;
let y =  Math.trunc(x/3);

for(let i=0; i<=y; i++){
    a = x - (3*i);
    console.log(a);
}
```